# AWS S3 Failed connect to endpoint Spring Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-s3

I just started learning about Java Spring Boot and I would like to make an application to upload image online to AWS S3 server. However, when I want to test the AWS connection this `Failed to connect to endpoint` error comes out. Does anyone knows the solution and reason for this? Thank you so much!
The full error logs are:

```
2020-08-09 08:53:37.467  INFO 17216 --- [           main] com.springtrial.awsimageupload.Main      : Starting Main on DESKTOP-1L8IA4K with PID 17216 (C:\Users\Nata\Documents\code\spring-java\aws-image-upload\target\classes started by Nata in C:\Users\Nata\Documents\code\spring-java\aws-image-upload)
2020-08-09 08:53:37.475  INFO 17216 --- [           main] com.springtrial.awsimageupload.Main      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-09 08:53:40.450  INFO 17216 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-09 08:53:40.470  INFO 17216 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-09 08:53:40.470  INFO 17216 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-09 08:53:41.054  INFO 17216 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-09 08:53:41.055  INFO 17216 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3442 ms
2020-08-09 08:53:50.945  WARN 17216 --- [           main] com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document). Failed to connect to service endpoint: 

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:367) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion(EC2MetadataUtils.java:282) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.tryDetectRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:59) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.getRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:50) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.determineRegionFromRegionProvider(AwsClientBuilder.java:475) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:458) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.835.jar:na]
    at com.springtrial.awsimageupload.config.AmazonConfig.s3(AmazonConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springtrial.awsimageupload.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f527e04.CGLIB$s3$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springtrial.awsimageupload.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f527e04$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c8017c7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.springtrial.awsimageupload.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f527e04.s3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.10.BUILD-20200807.013348-44.jar:2.2.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.springtrial.awsimageupload.Main.main(Main.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Is the instance running in a private subnet?

Comment: @Marcin it is running on my computer localhost:8080

Comment: Please post the code that you used and the environment details.